Почему не работает замена номера телефона?


    $('#modalPhone').inputmask({
    mask: "+7 (999) 999 - 99 - 99",
    definitions: {
    '9': { validator: "[0-9]", cardinality: 1 }
    }
    });



Он заменяет вторую цифру на 9, есть е идентичных сайта только на одном код работает а на другом нет, все версии библиотек одинаковые - посути это копии сайтов. Мстика какаято. Мб есть другие способы сделать тоже самое?
